# Parser Error for RadioButton In Repeater with Sitecore

Tags: asp.net, webforms, sitecore, sitecore6

I'm receiving a Parser Error (`The server tag is not well formed.`) for the following Radio Button control when, and only when, I add the `Text` property.

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="RepeaterPanel" CssClass="radio-list">
    <asp:Repeater ID="RadioRepeater" runat="server" ItemType="Sitecore.Data.Items.Item">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="radio-control">
                <asp:RadioButton 
                    runat="server" 
                    Text="<%#: Item["Text"] %>"
                    GroupName="<%#: DataSource.Name %>" 
                />
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</asp:Panel>
```

The error is as follows:

```
Line 9:              <ItemTemplate>
Line 10:                 <div class="radio-control">
Line 11:                     <asp:RadioButton 
Line 12:                         runat="server" 
Line 13:                         Text="<%#: Item["Text"] %>"
```

I've tried using `<%# Item["Text"] %>` and `<%# Eval("Name") %>` (just to get something working) as well as all variations I can think of between those three (`#:` and `#`). I need to get data from the data bound item (`Sitecore.Data.Items.Item`) so using the `<%= %>` syntax does not seem to be appropriate.

And to make things more complicated, when adding the output below (as follows) the Radio Button works flawlessly, without complaint.

```
<%#: Item["Text"] %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple consecutive `"` here:

```
Text = "<%#: Item["Text"] %>"
```

Instead try

```
Text = '<%#: Item["Text"] %>'
```

Comment: Thanks... been staring at this for too long. Would be nice if the parser error told me what it was encountering specifically.

Comment: Using `'<%#: Item["Text"] %>'` did the trick. I was just using too many quotes and was completely oblivious to it, looking for something more complex.